# PHP Stripe \Stripe\AccountLink Class Not Found

Tags: php, stripe-payments

In the code below, the \Stripe\Account class is successfully called but an error gets thrown saying \Stripe\AccountLink class is not found. What I'm I missing here?

```
 include("../../bin/core/libs/stripe/init.php");

 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(self::STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

 $account = \Stripe\Account::create([
         'country' => 'US',
         'type' => 'express',
 ]);
  
 $account_links = \Stripe\AccountLink::create([
                                          'account' => $account["id"],
                                          'refresh_url' => self::APP_URL . "/referralprogram/refresh/",
                                          'return_url' => self::APP_URL . "/referralprogram/return/",
                                          'type' => 'account_onboarding',
                                        ]);
```

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia pure php no framework

Comment: Sure, but that’s a LIBRARY, that most likely you have downloaded from github

Comment: [stripe-php definitely does include AccountLink.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/init.php#L75). This looks like it should work. Can you copy and paste the entire error message? Can you verify that you have the correct version of the library that includes `require __DIR__ . '/lib/AccountLink.php';` on line 75 of init.php?

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia  yes I'm using the Stripe-php library

Comment: @HPierce I updated to the latest version of stripe-php and it now works

Comment: @ShaneJupiter - Nice! Glad to hear it you solved it!